# How to get actual mean of k folds by using GridSearchCV?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using GridSearchCV with cv = KFold(n_splits=10), scoring='accuracy' with some testing SVM (c=1, gamma=1).

For this testing, I am using only vector of 51 values, and another one of 51 binary responses.

My results look like this:

```
 'split0_test_score': array([ 0.16666667]), 'split1_test_score': array([ 0.4]), 'split2_test_score': array([ 0.8]), 'split3_test_score': array([ 0.6]), 'split4_test_score': array([ 0.2]), 'split5_test_score': array([ 1.]), 'split6_test_score': array([ 0.2]), 'split7_test_score': array([ 0.]), 'split8_test_score': array([ 0.4]), 'split9_test_score': array([ 0.6]),
```

'mean_test_score': array([ 0.43137255]) ...

The problem is that mean score is not the actual mean score of all folds test score (it should be 0.4367). Is there a way to get real mean of all folds from GridSearchCV? Or do I have to extract it manually?
Thank you

Comment: What are the parameters you are sending to GridSearchCV?

Comment: As I stated, I am sending following:
svm (or svc), rbf, C=1, gamma = 1, cv = kFold (n_splits=10), njobs=-1, scoring = 'accuracy') 
And I fit it onto my two vectors one response  and one with values (of feature). 
It seems that on leave one out the mean is fine (maybe it seems fine because there are 51, so it converges using this scoring method).
I ended up using mean of the values extracted from folds manually, but it is still strange for me that this happens.

Comment: That means you are not using any multiple values for parameters that you want to check, so why use gridSearchCV.

Comment: I am using it only for testing, so this is just an example. I think it should work as well. Also, I tried for multiple parameters and more features and I had the same problem if I remember well (that is how I got to this test example).

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed such discrepancies using GridSearchCV from Scikit-learn. Using my own test cases, the difference betwen the average (`numpy.mean`) over `splitX_test_score[i]` and `mean_test_score` from the attribute `cv_results_` is noticeable from the 17th decimal with 2 folds. With 10 folds, there are discrepancies from the 6th decimal.
I think this issue may be related to floating point precision. Please, could someone explain how exactly `mean_test_score` (which function is used, with which floating point precision)? Many thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I read the answer from Leena in the following topic: [sikit learn cv grid scores - Unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303813/sikit-learn-cv-grid-scores-unexpected-results/35495554#35495554). The difference is due to the parameter `iid`. If set to `False`, then `mean_test_score` is computed from mean value across folds.